# Prove that 2-by-2 identity matrix $I_2$ has infinitely many distinct square root matrices

Tags: matrices

Consider a square matrix $A$. Matrix $B$ is called as the square root of matrix $A$ if it satisfies $B^2 =
A$. Prove that $I_2$ has infinitely many distinct square root matrices, where $I_2$ is the identity matrix
of size $2\times2$.

Comment: Welcome on Math.SE ! Can you show us what you have already tried so that we know how to help you ?

Comment: Hint: a reflection is its own inverse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

Let $a \in \mathbb{R}$. Calculate $M^2$ where

$$M=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & a \\
0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}$$